# Image swipe view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, layout

I am searching a view for image gallery app. I searched and found [swipe views](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html) article, but couldn't find exact solution. I am looking for view like following image.

[image: image view]

I know to achieve top panel, I must use ActionBarSherlock since ActionBar doesn't support Android 2.3. But how they achieve to display images. And after someone click on a image, it will start new Activity.

I tried to achieve that with ListView, but it was harder than I thought. I think there is an easy way, but don't know how to search for it. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: @SaeidFarivar you are wrong grid view did not work with swipe..
like your gallery-item view..

Comment: @Isuru did you got any solution for your question? I am looking for same thing but unable to do. Please help..

Comment: @SaeidFarivar yes you are right we all see grid view but question is "image gallery app" like swipe..
means go into your phone gallery and when you have more images it is simply swipe on touch left to right and right to left..
Note: I am not talking about gallery view. Means don't open image for detail view just see as a tile..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture that you have shown is an example of gridview.
It can be acheived using GridView in layout file and an Adapter to place images as items of Grid.
Further the bottom translucent bar on each image can be placed using FrameLayout.
I have implemented the same thing in my application.

Look out for some examples on GridView.